# Which is the fastest way to erase in set?

Tags: c++, stl, stdset

I read the cpp reference there are three ways to erase in `std::set`.

1. `void erase (iterator position)`
2. `size_type erase (const value_type& val)`
3. `void erase (iterator first, iterator last)`

Assuming I already know the iterator, which is faster, erasing using iterator or erasing using value?

Comment: Think about it. Erasing the value must first search the set to find where to delete. If you have the iterator already, use it. If you are in doubt about speed, write a program to test it.

Comment: @slee Of course the fastest way is to use the iterator that already points to the erased elements.

Comment: With the iterator the `erase` function hopefully already have the information what node in the tree (or in the hash table for unordered sets) to remove. With the value `erase` function that node must first be found.

Comment: On the [cppreference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/erase), there is a Complexity section at the bottom that gives you the complexity of each overload.  Using that you can see that `1` is the fastest way.

Comment: You got a typo in return types. If you have the value, then erase by value; otherwise erase by iterator.

Comment: @NathanOliver: While I agree that (practically speaking) 1 will normally be the fastest way, you can't safely deduce that from complexity. Complexity tells you asymptotic behavior on a (purely theoretical) set of infinite size, not how things are going to act on your real set of strictly finite size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For performance related questions, it is important to carefully define the operations, data, software stack and hardware that are of interest and then *actually do the measurements*. And, since developing code involves the weighing of alternatives, it is often useful to know roughly the magnitude of the performance difference. The results can often be surprising and informative.

For this question I will make the assumption that we want to understand the performance of the different `std::set` `erase` methods for the type `uint64_t` on a dataset of 1M elements. Since OP did not specify, I will use some common hardware / software that is available to me.

The following code measures the time to delete all 1M elements from a `std::set` using both iterators and values. It does the deletions in three different orders: sorted, reverse sorted and random. This results is six different measurements. The code and build instructions are available on [GitHub](https://github.com/cpp-core/so.git).

```cpp
#include "core/util/tool.h"
#include "core/chrono/stopwatch.h"
#include "core/util/random.h"

template<class Work>
void measure(std::ostream& os, std::string_view desc, Work&& work) {
    chron::StopWatch timer;
    timer.mark();
    work();
    auto millis = timer.elapsed_duration<std::chrono::milliseconds>().count();
    os << fmt::format("{:>16s}: {:5d} ms", desc, millis) << endl;
}

int tool_main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    ArgParse opts
        (
         argValue<'n'>("number", 100000, "Number of elements"),
         argFlag<'v'>("verbose", "Verbose diagnostics")
         );
    opts.parse(argc, argv);
    auto n = opts.get<'n'>();
    // auto verbose = opts.get<'v'>();

    using Set = std::set<uint64_t>;
    using Elements = std::vector<Set::value_type>;
    using Iterators = std::vector<Set::iterator>;

    Set src_data;
    Elements elements;
    for (auto i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        src_data.insert(i);
        elements.push_back(i);
    }

Set data = src_data;
    Iterators iterators(n);
    for (auto i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        iterators[i] = data.find(i);
    measure(cout, "iterator-ordered", [&]() {
        for (auto iter : iterators) {
            data.erase(iter);
        }
    });

    data = src_data;
    for (auto i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        iterators[i] = data.find(i);
    std::reverse(iterators.begin(), iterators.end());
    measure(cout, "iterator-reverse", [&]() {
        for (auto iter : iterators)
            data.erase(iter);
    });

    data = src_data;
    for (auto i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        iterators[i] = data.find(i);
    std::shuffle(iterators.begin(), iterators.end(), core::rng());
    measure(cout, "iterator-random", [&]() {
        for (auto iter : iterators)
            data.erase(iter);
    });

    data = src_data;
    measure(cout, "value-ordered", [&]() { ;
            for (auto value : elements)
                data.erase(value);
    });

    data = src_data;
    std::reverse(elements.begin(), elements.end());
    measure(cout, "value-reverse", [&]() { ;
            for (auto value : elements)
                data.erase(value);
    });

    data = src_data;
    std::shuffle(elements.begin(), elements.end(), core::rng());
    measure(cout, "value-random", [&]() { ;
            for (auto value : elements)
                data.erase(value);
    });
    
    return 0;
}
```

A typical run produces something like the following:

```
$ make set_erase_performance && set_erase_performance -n 1000000
iterator-ordered:    23 ms
iterator-reverse:    31 ms
 iterator-random:   110 ms
   value-ordered:    65 ms
   value-reverse:    79 ms
    value-random:   376 ms
```

If we take the `iterator-ordered` performance for the M1 as 1, here are the relative times across some select hardware / software combinations (M1 Max / Mac OSX 13, Intel Xeon E5-2698 / Ubuntu 20.04, AMD 7601 / Ubuntu 22.06).

| algo \ cpu | M1 | Intel | AMD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| iterator-ordered | 1.0 | 1.3 | 2.3 |
| iterator-reverse | 1.4 | 7.3 | 4.2 |
| iterator-random | 4.8 | 6.3 | 21 |
| value-ordered | 2.8 | 5.7 | 7.0 |
| value-reverse | 3.4 | 7.1 | 8.4 |
| value-random | 16 | 28 | 71 |

As expected, using an iterator to erase the element is the fastest method and we have at least some data on how much faster because that is often the actual question of interest. The performance variation both across platforms and across orderings is interesting.